# Count carriage returns in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm running the following code to set a limit on characters in a textarea:

```
(function($){ 
 $.fn.extend({  
     limit: function(limit,element) {

        var interval, f;
        var self = $(this);

        $(this).focus(function(){
            interval = window.setInterval(substring,100);
        });

        $(this).blur(function(){
            clearInterval(interval);
            substring();
        });

        substringFunction = "function substring(){ var val = $(self).val();var length = val.length + carriages;if(length > limit){$(self).val($(self).val().substring(0,limit));}";
        if(typeof element != 'undefined')
            substringFunction += "if($(element).html() != limit-length){$(element).html((limit-length<=0)?'0':limit-length);}"

        substringFunction += "}";

        eval(substringFunction);



        substring();

    } 
}); 
})(jQuery);
```

The area my users are entering text into can fit a maximum of 1500 characters.  The problem is that it can only fit a maximum of 10 lines.  If they enter 25 characters on one line before entering a carriage return, the characters total needs to be at 150, not 26.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why are you using eval?  Please don't us eval.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  I hired someone to build the site for me, now I'm going through and changing things.  Do you have a link to a different snippet I should use?  This level of javascript is over my head.

Comment: It's over your head because it's _way_ over engineered... It's using advanced meta-programming features where plain simple code would have done just fine. Be careful who you hire to write JavaScript for you. They may not be doing you any favors.

Answer (score 7):

```
var string = "foo\nbar\nbaz";
console.log(string);
// foo
// bar
// baz

var lines = string.split(/\n/).length;
```

Simply split the string by every new lines, and then see how many lines you have.

Comment: Not sure if this will do the trick for me.  First, I would like the user to be notified of the characters they have used up.  If each line is worth 150 characters, the difference needs to be subtracted from the total if they carriage return early.  When they reach the maximum, they shouldn't be allowed to enter anything further.

Comment: You asked how to count new lines, this is how. How to prevent input based on some function you run on each keystroke is another question.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using regex that is always very efficient. Note that this solution counts retuen carriages, NOT lines

```js
const string = "foo\nbar\nbaz";
const lines = (string.match(/\n/g) || []).length;
console.log(lines);
```